# How to make iteration in React js and split into two groups?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666061/how-do-i-split-my-items-into-two-groups), I have some items and I want to iterate them in React js. Here is my items and component:

```
const itemlists = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "url": "/one",
    "title": "One",
    "category": "News"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "url": "/two",
    "title": "Two",
    "category": "News"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "url": "/three",
    "title": "Three",
    "category": "News"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "url": "/four",
    "title": "Four",
    "category": "News"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "url": "/five",
    "title": "Five",
    "category": "News"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "url": "/six",
    "title": "Six",
    "category": "News"
  }
]
```

Cards component

```
class Cards extends Component {
    render() {
        const renderData = itemlists.map((item, i) => {
            return (
                <div className="card-row" key={i}>

                    <div className="card-content">
                        <div className="card-left">

                            // This should be 2 items in left side
                            <div className="item">{item.title}</div>

                        </div>
                        <div className="card-right">

                            // This should be 4 items in right side
                            <div className="item">{item.title}</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="pagination">
                        <a href={item.url}>More in {item.category}</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            )
        })
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {renderData}
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

I got parsing error when I put `if else statement` within `return`, for example:

```
<div className="card-left">
    {
      ---- this if statement gives error ----
      if((items + 1) % 3 === 0) {
        ....
      }
    }
    <div className="item">{item.title}</div>
</div>
```

My goal is to split those items into two groups (2 in left side and 4 in right side). I Also want to put pagination link below in `<div className="pagination">`. I have been confusing in logic. Let me know if there was simple way to achive my goal.

Regards.

Comment: Try this: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if-else inside jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046037/if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of an `if-else` statement use a [ternary operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator) like:

```
(items + 1) % 3 === 0 ? doThis() : doThat()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html)

> if-else statements don't work inside JSX. This is because JSX is just syntactic sugar for function calls and object construction.

So instead of `if` you need to use ternary operator.
Example of ternary operator is as follows

```
<div className="card-left">
    {
         (items + 1) % 3 === 0 ? Task1 : Task2 

    }
    <div className="item">{item.title}</div>
</div>
```